# looking for bash script which can move HDFS data

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs

I am looking to oraganize/move data from hdfs://data/backup to proper HDFS folder.

```
e.g: hdfs://data/backup/a/1 to hdfs://data/a/1
hdfs://data/backup/b/1 to hdfs://data/b/2
hdfs://data/backup/c/1 to hdfs://data/c/3
hdfs://data/backup/d/1 to hdfs://data/d/4
```

Data under these folders are on date and further hour wise

If the data of that hour already exist on the destination folder, override it with the data from ecbackup.

e.g

```
hdfs://data/backup/a/1/merged/20190608/1 -> hdfs://data/a/1/merged/20190608/01
......
hdfs://data/backup/a/1/merged/20190608/17 -> hdfs://data/a/1/merged/20190608/17
....
hdfs://data/backup/a/1/merged/20190608/23 -> hdfs://data/a/1/merged/20190608/23
```

this is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash



SOURCE='hdfs://data/backup/audio_archive'
DEST='hdfs://data/a'
source_files=( $(hdfs dfs -ls -r "${SOURCE}" | awk '/^-/ {print $NF}') )
SOURCE="${SOURCE%/}"
SOURCE_DIR="${SOURCE//hdfs:\//}"
DEST="${DEST%/}"
for file_ in "${source_files[@]}"; do
    if [[ ! $file_ =~ /[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+ ]]; then
    continue
    fi
    dest_="${file_#${SOURCE_DIR}}"
    dest="${DEST}${dest_}"
    dest_dir="${dest%/*}"
    # NOTE: Remove `echo` after checking the output to
    # perform the real actions
    echo hdfs dfs -mkdir -p "${dest_dir}"
    echo hdfs dfs -mv -f "hdfs:/${file_}" "${dest}"
    echo
done
```

I am getting below error

```
20/01/31 18:16:10 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
20/01/31 18:16:10 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
20/01/31 18:16:10 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is: ; destination host is:  , while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over ... after 1 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 1423ms.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!!.. Can you please edit your question and share little more details on what you have tried or the exact error you are facing so that it becomes easy to help you.

Comment: Based on error it looks like KERBEROS ticket problem. Run klist to see tickets. Check if the same code runs in terminal line by line and fix minor syntax errors if found. If it runs fine then try creating ticket in bash script using kinit command and KRB5CCNAME at beginning.